# React npm start Fatal Error when starting an app that was working fine before laptop crashed

Tags: reactjs, pycharm, npm-start

My react project was working fine, my computer crashed (screen faded like it was turning off mid-typing which it has done before). Now when I try to run 'npm start' I get the Fatal Error in the console as below, I've tried excluding the latest part of the code I was writing but that hasn't worked, changed the app but same thing. I've seen answers that relate to loops but can't see how that's my problem, any help would be appreciated.

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 170763823
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 000000D6165FE6D0
 1: 00007FF6FD86D51F node_api_throw_syntax_error+175743
 2: 00007FF6FD7837BF v8::CTypeInfoBuilder<void>::Build+12703
 3: 00007FF6FE62D852 V8_Fatal+162
 4: 00007FF6FE13AB05 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArray+101
 5: 00007FF6FDFBFF43 v8::internal::FeedbackNexus::ic_state+65795
 6: 00007FF6FDFDEAC0 v8::Message::GetIsolate+15600
 7: 00007FF6FDE2AE10 v8::internal::CompilationCache::IsEnabledScriptAndEval+25952
 8: 00007FF6FE338051 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+558193
 9: 00007FF67EA19B8A
```

I have a number of apps in the project so I switched to another one and got the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried with 1) `npm cache clean --force` and 2) removing `package-lock.json` and `npm install` ?

Comment: TBH, it sounds like something about Node may have gotten corrupted; I'd remove `node_modules` and do `npm i` again, and if that doesn't help, reinstall Node too...

Comment: thank you both, seem to have fixed it by running npx update-browserlist-db@latest which was suggested before the error and it's now working, seems very odd though

Answer (score 0):

ok, managed to fix it but will leave this here for anyone who runs into a similar issue and gets focused on a memory issue. There was a message above this  which you can see below, installing this did the trick!

```
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx update-browserslist-db@latest
```